# My hope will get me killed - Is it a correct phrase as an alternative to the phrase I will get killed by my hope?

Tags: sentence-construction

This phrase was used in my student´s English poem.

Comment: It's not super clear which phrase was used in your student's poem, are you asking "my hope will get me killed" is an alternative to your student's line "I will get killed by my hope" or vice versa? What do you mean by correct? Do you believe it the first is ungrammatical or that it sounds particularly awkward? And as we all know, poetry is an art form, the words and images that a poet conjures up belong to the world of *artistic licence*

Comment: Thanks, I meant both (ungrammatical/ particularly ackward)

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically correct.  It has a slightly different meaning, because "... will get me killed" is about an indirect effect.

"My hope will get me killed" is better than "...will kill me", or "I will get killed by..." since the meaning is probably figurative (I don't think it means "my hope" will stab me with a knife).  It is, I assume, deliberately "weird".

Comment: Thanks, your comment fits the issue

Comment: If this answer has been useful or solved your problem, consider marking it as "accepted".